# Migrate users to firebase auth, force uid generation before login

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

We are building an app that will launch soon on which users can authenticate using Firebase (Google and Facebook). Previously we have run a website to preregister users. On this website users can authenticate through Google and Facebook. On the website we haven't been using Firebase authentication.

The problem is that a lot of our code in the app works on the firebase auth uid. If a user that has signed in on the website contacts another user through the app, we connect them using the Firebase uid. This is a problem if the user hasn't logged in on the app after registering on the website. (The uid we keep in the backend changes from FB or Google uid to Firebase uid).

How should we connect the users on the website to the users in firebase? Is there a way we can predict/force the uid to something we can control?
Ideally registrations on the website should also still work after go-live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your Google/Facebook user to Firebase Auth using the Firebase CLI SDK and then use Firebase to authenticate these users after migration. During migration you can use whatever UID you need for these users: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authimport

Comment: Thanks for your advice. We migrated the users to Firebase using the CLI SDK, using their Facebook/Google ID as uid. On the website we have kept the Google/Facebook login SDK and exchanged the ID token/auth token for  a Firebase credential when logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a server where you can create users with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user). By default, a random `uid` is created, but you have the option to assign a specific `uid`. Here's the website's example using Node.js:

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  uid: "some-uid",
  email: "user@example.com",
  phoneNumber: "+11234567890"
})
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
  });
```

The Admin SDK also offers the functionality for Java and Python if you prefer one of those languages.

Comment: Thanks, however this doesn't seem to work for federated accounts (Facebook, Google) => https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/45 . Any other ideas?